# Custom shortcode is not working in text widget

Tags: shortcode, widgets

I have created function for creating shortcode in function.php. This function looks like below

```
function related_category_sidebar() {
    include_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/sabai-directory/assets/templates/template_related_category.php');
}
add_shortcode( 'related_category', 'related_category_sidebar' );
```

Now, I have created custom widget sidebar like :

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'theme_slug_widgets_init' );
function theme_slug_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
         'name' => __( 'Related Category', 'theme-slug' ),
         'id' => 'rel_cat',
         'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'theme-slug' ),
         'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
         'after_widget'  => '</li>',
         'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
         'after_title'   => '</h2>',
     ) );
}
```

Now, I have add text widget in this `Related category` widget area. Then after I have called widget area in custom file as :

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('rel_cat'); ?>
```

But shorcode is not working. Here, I have used `<?php echo do_shortcode('[related_category]'); ?>` direct in file so its working.

But, I want to use shortcode using widget area so what should I have to change in my code?

Comment: Does your theme support shortcodes at all in the widget area? Try to find in your theme functions.php: `add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode', 11 );` If that is missing please add it and lets hope it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcodes need to *return* data, not echo it - use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to capture the output of the include and return it:

```
function related_category_sidebar() {
    ob_start();
    include WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/sabai-directory/assets/templates/template_related_category.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Then you will also need to do as Charles suggested and enable shortcodes for text widgets:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode', 11 );
```